# string regex on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

how to make sure my string format must be like this :

```
locker_number=3,email=ucup@gmail.com,mobile_phone=091332771331,firstname=ucup
```

i want my string format `"key=value,"

how to make regex for check my string on ruby?

Comment: I think it would be something like `\w+=.*?(,|$)`. I don't know in Ruby though how you'd compose that.

Comment: The regex is easy enough, but where is this string coming from, looks like it should be a hash

Comment: Yeah, it really pays to use a solid data format for this kind of thing - such as JSON.  Otherwise you end up having to deal with goofy scenarios like equals signs or commas in the keys or values.

Comment: you right @chris85, thanks

regex in ruby : (/\w+=.*?(,|$)/ =~ my_string) == 0

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure what that looked like in Ruby. Is this all set, should I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will find what you're after.

```
\w+=.*?(,|$)
```

If you want to capture each pairing use

```
(\w+)=(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

http://rubular.com/r/A2ernIzQkq

The `\w+` is one or more occurrences of a character a-z, 1-9, or an underscore. The `.*?` is everything until the first `,` or the end of the string (`$`). The pipe is `or` and the `?:` tells the regex no to capture that part of the expression.

Per your comment it would be used in Ruby as such,

```
(/\w+=.*?(,|$)/ =~ my_string) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\w+=.*?(,|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK1kS8/1)**

You can use this code:

```
"<your string>" =~ /\w+=.*?(,|$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?  It's picky about the last element not ending with ,.  But it doesn't enforce the need for no commas in the key or no equals in the value.

```
'locker_number=3,email=ucup@gmail.com,mobile_phone=091332771331,firstname=ucup' =~ /^([^=]+=[^,]+,)*([^=]+=[^,]+)$/
```